# NodeJs Scoping in streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

## Very cut down version of what I do :

I have some variables defined, but I can't access them inside a stream.

```js
const myVar = "MyVar";

discordBot.on('ready', () => {
   console.log(MyVar); // myVar undefined
})
```

Shouldn't myVar be available in `discordBot.on('ready')` ?

## Full non cut down example

```js
const toggleUser = 'tUser';

const config = {
  [`${toggleUser}`]: true,
};

bot.on('ready', () => {
  const {
    [toggleUser]: toggleUser, // toggleUser is not defined
  } = config;
}
```

`config` is defined and available through closure, but `toggleUser` isn't ... ?

Comment: change `[toggleUser]: toggleUser` so that `toggleUser` to the right of the `:` isn't the same as your global constant

Comment: it should actually say it's already redefined, are you sure that's not full non cut version?

Comment: @NickParsons  just realized that I can't have the same variable name from closure and in the function through destructuring

Comment: @emrhzc I got confused by the undefined, but yes it is either giving me undefined or cannot access variable before allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that I can't have the same variable name from closure and a destructured variable name in the function ...